# Edit files from remote server with VS Code

Tags: ssh, git

My university has its own server used for development and we can SSH into the server to access files. I use WSL to SSH into the server and I am able to see all my git repositories. I know I can use vim to edit the files in the repository, but I would prefer to use VS Code. I am not sure how to open these files in VS Code since it doesn't show up in file explorer of my own machine. What is the best way to open the file in VS Code so that it is still connected to the same git repository?

Comment: Why not just clone the Git repository...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the extension of:

- [Remote Development from VSCODE-SSH](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack)

[image]

or :

- [Remote-WSl SSH](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl)

[image]

#### Git

For git the VSCode itself (by default) already has its own plugins although there are a wide variety of extensions in the [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode)

### Links

- [Remote Development using SSH](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh)